# WordPress Phone Verification

Tags: spam, membership, hacks, verification, sms

Is there a way to check verified members phone numbers by sending code to their mobile phones just like Facebook does?

This would be very handy to stop spammers and allows only one user per phone number.

Answer (score 3):

Of course this is possible it would just require some custom coding.  This is an open ended question so I'll give you an open ended answer of how I may go about this.

1. [Add phone number field to user contact](http://wpmodder.com/how-to-add-and-delete-contact-info-fields-for-your-users-960.html)
2. Use the [profile_update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) hook to store a random code associated with that number
3. Create a verify phone number page
4. Use [Twilio](http://twillio.com) or [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp) to send the user the code from the database
5. Have them type it into a box and then check to see if the values match

So yes, it's possible but no it's not going to be the easiest thing to do.